# Need to perform authentication without giving the credentials from Salesforce Login screen from Mule

Tags: authentication, oauth, salesforce, mule, salesforce-communities

Use case Scenario: Mule to Salesforce redirection of user to home page without username and password

User details will come from source and based on details i will validate and create the user in Salesforce using Mule.
after creating the user in Salesforce **without logging in**. i want to redirect the user to enter Salesforce community home page.

Here I am able to redirect to the Salesforce page but how can i enter to community page without logging in

Any suggestion or solutions also welcome but here i require for multiple users

Comment: Can you access Salesforce community page in a browser without authentication (ie in an incognito/private window)?

Comment: Unfortunately no @aled. If there is any other alternative approach plz guide

Comment: If the page itself doesn't allow unauthenticated access, there is nothing Mule can do about it. Remember that Mule would execute the same HTTP requests that you would in the browser.

Comment: Can we use Any other authentication method.. like oauth

Answer (score 0):

If the page requires authentication to be accessed you have to provide that authentication, there is no way around it. You can use any authentication method supported by the HTTP Requester, including [OAuth 2 Authorization Code](https://docs.mulesoft.com/http-connector/1.5/http-authentication#oauth2-authorization-code) and [OAuth 2 Client Credentials](https://docs.mulesoft.com/http-connector/1.5/http-authentication#oauth2cc). I don't have an example like you want but it is theoretically possible at least.